# Composer install Issue For Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento, installation, composer-php

## composer.json file

```
`"repositories": {
   "0": {
   "type": "composer",
   "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
  },
  "gitlab.test.in/277": {
  "type": "composer",
  "url": "https://gitlab.test.in/api/v4/group/277/-/packages/composer/packages.json"
 }
},``
```

## auth.json

```
   `{
      "gitlab-token": {
      "gitlab.privateinstance.com": "bjC2RG4J4tcYksZRsxMZ"
     }
   }`
```

php version = 8.1
magento version = 2.4.6

composer install
|--------------------------It is not working getting below error
|
In CurlDownloader.php line 623:

The "https://gitlab.test.in/api/v4/group/277/-/packages/composer/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found):
{"message":"404 Group Not Found"}

Any solution will be help full

- I am trying to run composer insatll but it is not able to download respective packages

Comment: A 404 error indicates that the URL you try to request does not exist. Did you check that?

Comment: yes i checked that URL is exit